# Why does tqdm also import colorama when I pip install it. It makes ıt red

Tags: python, windows, tqdm, colorama

When I install tdqm It also comes with colorama and It makes all the tqdm progress bars red? How can I change that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*How can I change that?*

According to [tqdm PyPI page](https://pypi.org/project/tqdm/) it does accept `colour` as argument, simple example

```
from tqdm import tqdm
for i in tqdm(range(100),colour="white"):
    pass
```